# Few arguments to function

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting a " too few argument to function" message

```
result = total_area (diameter/3);
```

and same message come when its volume.

I tried calling both base and perimeter, as height but got a different message, also tried changing the numbers but same.

Comment: Have you looked at the function's signature? The method most likely requires more than one parameter.

Comment: Can you post code of your function definition?

Comment: what is the function signature for `total_area()`?

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory. `total_area` requires more than one parameter. Check the function declaration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To help us help you, we need more information, such as the definition for the `total_area` function.  It would also help if you told us what compiler you were using, and if you copied and pasted the *exact* error message you are getting.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is unfortunately not complete enough to get a useful answer. Posting a function call that produces some problem without posting the corresponding function definition is quite meaningless. Please include that, but I suspect that will already answer your question by itself.

Comment: No, i have not. Im actually new in this.

Comment: It's hard to help you if we have no idea how `total_area` is declared and what type diameter is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the definition of the function `total_area`, and you'll find it is defined to take more parameters.

You only gave it one parameter (`diameter/3`, aka. one-third of the diameter).
This function probably needs a diameter and a height, and perhaps some other parameters
(*we don't really know because you aren't showing us the definition of the function!*)

When you find out what it needs, you'll probably want to call it like:

```
result = total_area (diameter/3, height, width);  // See the other parameters??!
```

Comment: I kept trying to upload the code but I couldn't but thank you all.

Comment: @user3376487 There is no option to upload the code as a whole, you need to copy and paste the interesting parts into the question. If you don't know exactly what to include, say so in your question and look at the comments, most people will tell you what info is missing. You can also edit your question if you have new infos for us. 
And one last thing: If the answer by abelenky helped you solve your issue, please mark it as the answer to give him credit.